# How can I access field error by using jsp EL, not OGNL in jsp?

Tags: jsp, struts2, valuestack, xwork

I wander if I can access field error(put into the `ValueStack` by validator interceptor) by using JSP EL in JSP?

Comment: Is field error list??

Comment: What's wrong with using `<s:fieldError />` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are a list in valuestack, named feilderrors and we can use jsp EL access this list